# How to use react-hook-form v7 with reactstrap 9?

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form, reactstrap

I'm currently trying to create a form with react-hook-form **v7** and reactstrap 9, using react 18. Here's my current implementation but in my console logs, the data is returning an `undefined`. If you guys could tell me how to properly integrate them, it would be helpful. **Thanks a lot!**

```
  const { register, handleSubmit } = useForm();

  const onSubmit = (data) => {
    //here, the output is --> {email: undefined, password: undefined}
    console.log("sign in form data", data);
  };

// Sample Form
 <Form inline onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
      <FormGroup className="mb-2">
        <Label className="auth-label" htmlFor="email">
          Email address*
        </Label>
        <Input
          id="email"
          name="email"
          placeholder=""
          type="email"
          className="auth-input"
          {...register("email")}
        />
      </FormGroup>
      <Button block className="auth-button mt-4">
        Login
      </Button>
 </Form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to define register variable as follows:

```
const { ref, ...sampleName } = register("name");
```

and use this ref inside Reactstrap Input

```
<Input innerRef={ref} {...sampleName}/>
```

Please see sandbox here: https://codesandbox.io/s/reactstrap-sandbox-forked-z2uxl?file=/src/index.js:808-842

Answer (score 1):

Improving @Eray's answer
You can make an atomic component for all inputs

```
import { Input } from "reactstrap";

const FormInput = ({ register, name, validations, ...rest }) => {
  const { ref, ...registerField } = register(name, validations);

  return <Input innerRef={ref} {...registerField} {...rest} />;
};

export default FormInput;
```

And use it like below:

```
  <FormGroup>
    <Label>Email</Label>
    <FormInput type="email" name="email" register={register} validations={{ required: "Bu alan zorunludur!"}} />
    <FormFeedback>{errors.email}</FormFeedback>
  </FormGroup>
```